# Create dictionary with pairs from column from pandas dataframe using regex

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Original': [92,93,94,95,100,101,102],
             'Sub_90': [99,98,99,100,102,101,np.nan],
             'Sub_80': [99,98,99,100,102,np.nan,np.nan],
             'Gen_90': [99,98,99,100,102,101,101],
             'Gen_80': [99,98,99,100,102,101,100]})
```

I would like to create the following dictionary

```
{
    'Gen_90': 'Original',
    'Sub_90': 'Gen_90',
    'Gen_80': 'Original',
    'Sub_80': 'Gen_80',
 }
```

using `regex` (because at my original data I also have `Gen_70, Gen_60, ... , Gen_10` and `Sub_70, Sub_60, ... , Sub_10`)

So I would like to create pairs of `Sub` and `Gen` for the same `_number` and also pairs or the `Original` with the `Gen`s

How could I do that ?

Comment: The logic is unclear, can you clarify it? Also the generalization is unclear, do you want to include `Gen_70` etc. or exclude them?

Comment: You don't need regex at all. You already have a good naming convention. A root name "Original" and a same pattern for columns Gen_XX and Sub_XX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
gen_cols = df.filter(like='Gen_').columns
sub_cols = df.filter(like='Sub_').columns
d = dict(zip(sorted(sub_cols), sorted(gen_cols)))
d.update({g : 'Original' for g in gen_cols})
print(d)

{'Sub_80': 'Gen_80',
 'Sub_90': 'Gen_90',
 'Gen_90': 'Original',
 'Gen_80': 'Original'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
cols = df.sort_index(axis=1).columns
group = cols[::-1].str.extract(r'_(\d+)', expand=False)

out = {a: b for l in map(list, cols.groupby(group).values())
       for a,b in zip(l, ['Original']+l)}
```

This should work irrespective of the order of the input.

Output:

```
{'Gen_90': 'Original',
 'Sub_90': 'Gen_90',
 'Gen_80': 'Original',
 'Sub_80': 'Gen_80'}
```

Comment: interesting, i dont know if ive seen the `index.groupby()` be used before. is that equivalent to `df.groupby().groups`?

Comment: @rhug123 it's creating a `dict` directly (actually a PrettyDict), it's sometimes useful ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use dictionary comprehension with `replace` and sorting by number after `_`:

```
d = {x:'Original' if x.startswith('Gen') else x.replace('Sub','Gen')
      for x in sorted(df.columns.drop('Original'), 
                      key=lambda x: (-int(x.split('_')[1]), x.split('_')[0]))}
print (d)

{'Gen_90': 'Original', 
 'Sub_90': 'Gen_90', 
 'Gen_80': 'Original', 
 'Sub_80': 'Gen_80'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple loop:

```
l = sorted(df.columns[1:])  # exclude 'Original' column as it's common
d = {}

# split other columns into two sublist: one for Gen_XX and another for Sub_XX
for g, s in zip(l[:len(l)//2], l[len(l)//2:]):
    d[g] = 'Original'
    d[s] = g
```

Output:

```
>>> d
{'Gen_80': 'Original',
 'Sub_80': 'Gen_80',
 'Gen_90': 'Original',
 'Sub_90': 'Gen_90'}
```